# Sending and receiving hex values via serial port VB

Tags: vb.net, hex

In VB, I am able to send and receive strings with serial port using writeline() and readline() methods
But, how can I send and receive direct hex values via serial port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
Dim v As Byte
Open "COM1" For Binary As #1
v = <The value to write>
Put #1, , v
Close #1
```